# How to optimize MySQL to insert millions row?

Tags: mysql, optimization, insert

I need to insert millions rows into the MySQL database (InnoDB engine). I have a problem with time when the tables have big sizes. Almost all time is spent on insert queries. Maybe somebody know how to optimize it?

Comment: what is your query then?

Comment: Any other operations being performed on the table while you're inserting the data?

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to know how to set up MySQL to handle large volumes of inserts (or writes in general) or how to set it up to handle large amounts of data being stored?

Comment: One more question: do you need performance with large bulks of data (lots of inserts per transaction) or many small transactions?

Comment: One big transaction with millions insert queries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To import large bulk of data into InnoDB:

1. set in MySQL configuration

   - innodb_doublewrite = 0
   - innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50%+ system memory
   - innodb_log_file_size = 512M
   - log-bin = 0
   - innodb_support_xa = 0
   - innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
2. Add right after transaction start:

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;

   SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
3. Set right before transaction end:

   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

Comment: These optimisations just took me from doing 10,000 records every 10 minutes to 500,000 records, impressive.

Comment: Also set `sync_binlog = 0` in case of it is set to `1` (`0` is the default)

Comment: @zogby with `log_bin = 0` binlog is completely disabled, so `sync_binlog = 0` makes no difference.

Comment: The option `innodb_support_xa` can no longer be disabled. From the manual: `Disabling innodb_support_xa is no longer permitted as it makes replication unsafe and prevents performance gains associated with binary log group commit. `

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about a large number of `INSERT` statements, look into something called transactions. I'm quite certain that most (if not all) languages that do SQL support transactions. They will speed up anything involving writing to the DB. An added bonus is that if something goes wrong you can rollback the changes.