# Mysql design for logtable

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I would like to have advices about a mysql table design for a event logger.

Our needs :
- track a lot of action
- 10 000 actions / second
- 1 billion row at this time

Our hardware :
- 2*Xeon (seen as 32 CPU by the system)
- 128 GB RAM
- 6*600 SSD with Raid 10

Our table design :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_event` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_event` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_event_2` (`id_event`,`data`),
  KEY `id_inscri` (`id_inscri`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `id_event_4` (`id_event`,`date`,`data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8


ALTER TABLE `log_event`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `log_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_inscri`) REFERENCES `inscription` (`id_inscri`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Our problem :
 - We have an auto-increment as primary, but it is not really used. Is it a problem to remove it ? We will no have primary key if we remove it => How to identify a line ?

- We would like to do partionning, but with the foreign it seems to be impossible ?
- We don't do bulk insert. Is it a good idea to insert in a Memory table without index and copy data every 5 minutes ?

Do you have any idea to optimize ? Do you have best practice for this kind of system ?

Thanks !

François

Comment: Here is a somewhat related question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904720/how-to-optimize-mysql-to-insert-millions-row

Comment: The problem is not really to insert millions of row (we have billions) we the very high concurrency.
We are also looking for any optimisation / best pratices idea

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys of relational tables (relations) might have two types:

1. **Natural** - exists in subject area to completely determine each row of relational table.
   Natural primary keys might be **simple** (if consists of only one column), or **complex** (if consists more than one column). It is not recomended to set a natural primary key on large string column.
2. **Artificial** - special column, injected by database designer / developer to boost table performance, if natural key is complex, and have to be used in related table (is foreign key for something), or if it is simple, but is large and will produce data overhead while copied in related table as a foreign key, or if it is complex to search (for example, CRUD operations on `VARCHAR` IDs might be slower, than on `INT` IDs). There *might* be other reasons. ***TL;DR***: Artificial key - one special column, serving to completely determine each row of relational table and boost it's performance for CRUD operations.

> We have an auto-increment as primary, but it is not really used. Is it
>   a problem to remove it ? We will no have primary key if we remove it
>   => How to identify a line ?

If you do not need to reference your table to another tables (as source), then you may probably remove artificial key without any consequences. Still, I recomend you set any other `PRIMARY KEY` in this table to avoid data duplication, and for obviosity (if it matters).

Your table by itself (if properly [***normalized***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)) will have natural key as one of "key candidates". It might be complex one (consist of few columns). It is normal. But don't set primary for strings, because `PRIMARY` always have index, which will produce data overhead. If it is combination of `INT` or "*small*" `VARCHAR` columns, then it is normal.

**Consider as an option:** `id_event` + `id_user` + `date`.

---

> We don't do bulk insert. Is it a good idea to insert in a Memory table
>   without index and copy data every 5 minutes ?

It is not a bad idea. But it is not good idea, until it properly tested. Try to perform load-test, before real use.

If you not reference `MEMORY` table to others, then you still may join it with any other `InnoDB` table. But you will loose `InnoDB` functionality ([***referential integrity***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)). If lose of parent table `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not a concern, then it might be done. As for me, `InnoDB` is not so slow to switch table engine, in your case.